# Loading listview with dynamic images AND text from http?

Tags: android, listview

I need help with dynamic loading of images and text into a listview. I
have tried an example of lazy loading in listview but I'm having
trouble understanding how it retrieves text and images. I tried
creating a method to retrieve the image urls but not working
flawlessly.

Any solutions for this lazy loading or are there any other ways I
could do it? I need to display everything (images + text) from the
web.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at this [SO question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load these images first somewhere separatly, and after that you need to call the vector in your getView() method.
getView() is called every time you scroll trough list, so every time download the images, so you understand now why is better to download them first time in a local database, or somewhere else.